# Visual Studio Code task that takes c and cpp files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, glob

Trying to create `gcc` compile task for `Visual Studio Code` that takes both `*.cpp` and `*.c` files. I was trying to use patterns:

```
"${workspaceFolder}/*.c*"
```

This is not good, because it includes `*.code-workspace` file

```
("${workspaceFolder}/*.c*|${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp")
```

This is not treated at regular expression at all.

How to build pattern that takes `*.c` and `*.cpp` files?

tasks.json:

```
    {

                "type": "cppbuild",
                "label": "gcc",
                "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
                "args": [
                    "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                    "-g",
                    "${workspaceFolder}/*.c",
                    "-pthread",
                    "-o",
                    "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
                ],
                "options": {
                    "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
                },
                "problemMatcher": [
                    "$gcc"
                ],
                "group": {
                    "kind": "build",
                    "isDefault": true
                },
                "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/gcc"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This `tasks.josn` works for me.

```json
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "gcc",
            "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${workspaceFolder}/*.c",
                "${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp", # add a new line to specify the build pattern of cpp fle
                "-pthread",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/gcc"
        }
```

The structure of my demo project looks like this:

```sh
> tree .
.
├── entrypoints.cpp
├── entrypoints.h
├── main # the output binary
└── main.c
```